# How is do multi thread in CCS (Code Composer Studio)

Tags: multithreading

I try below code but doesn't work. Where is the wrong? If you do comment line Task_construct, code is work.
Full code is here "https://github.com/yildirimlutfi/yildirimlutfi/blob/main/multiThread".

```
void taskTimer(UArg arg1)//tick=1s
{
counter1++;
}

void taskThread(UArg arg0, UArg arg1)
{
counter2++;
}

void main()
{
Error_init(&eb);
Clock_Params_init(&clockParamsTimer);
clockParamsTimer.period = 100000;//1s
clockParamsTimer.startFlag = TRUE;
clockParamsTimer.arg = (UArg)0x5555;
myclock=Clock_create(taskTimer, 100, &clockParamsTimer, &eb);

Task_Struct taskStruct1;
Task_Params taskParams1;
Task_Params_init(&taskParams1);
taskParams1.stackSize=512;
taskParams1.priority=17;
Task_construct(&taskStruct1,(Task_FuncPtr)taskThread,&taskParams1,NULL);

Board_initGeneral();
BIOS_start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved.
taskParams1.priority=1;
but task one time was run. If be must two task how i must write code